# Tracking Key Combinations

Tags: autocompletion

I am trying to enter the i_CTRL-X Sub-Mode by pressing `c-x` in insert mode.  But `c-x` does nothing.  Is there any way to know what `c-x` in the insert mode is mapped to, so I can troubleshoot it?  I am using YouCompleteMe, which may cause the conflict, i am Just trying to figure out how to get line completion to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check what `<c-x>` is mapped to in insert mode with `:imap <c-x>`.

A useful debugging workflow is to start from scratch. First open Vim with no vimrc, e.g. from a shell type `vim -u NONE`. Verify that things work as expected. Then start with an empty vimrc file and copy parts of your original vimrc file one after another until you reproduce the problem.

Comment: Interesting, in both cases, with the `-u NONE` option and with my default configuration, checking the mapping returns `No Mapping Found`.  But <c-x> does work as expected with the `u NONE` option, but it does not work with my .vimrc file.  So, my assumption is to remove plug-ins one by one and see which one causes the issue.

Comment: Maybe a plugin changed some of the `timeout`/`timeoutlen`, `ttimeout`/`ttimeoutlen` values and your `<c-x>` simply times out very quickly.